# Navbar Subbar Menu Items Stay In Line

Tags: html, css, navbar, nav

I know there are similar questions asked here. I have spent a few hours fiddling and jsfiddling but can't seem to translate those questions to mine.  I get confused when the #call has so many different rules. #nav li ul li ul liii XD

I have a horizontal nav bar. 
Some items have dropdown menus, others do not.   I would like the sub-menu items to stay in line. If you take a look at my JSfiddle, the "partners" section, the text wraps. I'd like it to overflow to the right, it doesn't have to stay the same width of the parent dropdown menu.

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Peege151/hvgA9/1/

Here is my code
    HTML

```
<div id="navbar">
            <ul id="nav">
                <li> Home </li>
                <li>Services 
                    <ul>
                        <li> Full Suite of Services </li>                  
                    </ul>
                </li>   
                <li> <a href="case_studies/index"> Case Studies</a> 
                    <ul>    
                        <li><a href="case_studies/1"> Thing1</a> </li>
                        <li><a href="case_studies/2">Thing2 </a> </li>
                        <li><a href="case_studies/3"> Thing3 </a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>Partners 
                    <ul>
                        <li> Dude Middle Name Dood </li>
                        <li> Dude Middle Name Daaad </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>Contact Us</li>
            </ul>
        </div>`
```

And Here is my CSS

```
#navbar {
float:right;
margin-right: 10%;
width:50%;
background-color:blue;
text-align: right;
}
    #navbar ul{ 
background: linear-gradient(top, #efefef 0%, #bbbbbb 100%);  
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #efefef 0%, #bbbbbb 100%); 
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #efefef 0%,#bbbbbb 100%); 
box-shadow: 0px 0px 9px rgba(0,0,0,0.95);
padding: 0 10px;
border-radius: 10px;  
list-style: none;
position: relative;
display: inline-table;
  }
#navbar ul li {
position:relative;
```

display: inline-block

```
 }
 #navbar ul ul{
display:none; 
position:absolute;
top:1em;
left:0
}
#navbar ul > li:hover ul {
display:inline-table;
margin:0;
}
#navbar ul li:hover {
    background: #4b545f;
    background: linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%, #5f6975 40%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%, #5f6975 40%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%,#5f6975 40%);
}

#navbar li {
display: inline-block;
margin: 10px;
```

Thank you!

Comment: Did you try `white-space: nowrap;`?

Comment: I'm just not sure where to put it... #navbar ul > li hover ?

Comment: nope, just in the `#navbar li`. It prevents text from wrapping to the next line.

Comment: That helped, but now each <li> shows in-line...  I'd like person 2 to be beneath person 1, everything now is on one line

Comment: Try `#navbar ul li ul li { display: block; }`

Comment: You sir. Are the man. Answered.